# Are "more importantly" and "most importantly" different?

Tags: phrase-choice

Example sentence:

> He wanted to know what the sentence signified and, **most/more importantly,** what it implied.

Does it make any difference whether you use **most importantly** or **more importantly**, say, in sentences like this?

Comment: Are "more" and "most" different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"More" would tell us that the implication is of greater importance than the significance. "Most" might mean that the implication is **very** important or, if it is used as a *superlative*, that the implication is of the **greatest** importance.

"Most importantly" doesn't specifically **compare** the two. "More importantly" does.

Comment: Even if "more importantly" isn't comparing the two, it makes sense in this sentence (it's valid)?

Comment: You mean "most importantly"?

Comment: Ah, yes. "Most importantly."

Comment: @alexchenco: They both make sense and they are both valid, but their meanings are different. Do you want to say "**B is more important than A**", or "**B is extremely important**"? You decide! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You use **more** to identify the greater of two things: you use **most** to identify the greatest of many things.

In your sentence, there are only two things- **signified** and **implied**- so **more** is the correct word to use.